# Get only part of a file name in Awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I have tried

```
awk '{print FILENAME}'
```

And the result was full path of the file.
I want to get only the file name, example: from "`test/testing.test.txt`" I just want to get "`testing`" without "`.test.txt`".

Comment: does it have to be with awk... how about with basename

Comment: yes, cause i have these line of the records in a file, and i want to insert the filename into those line records. and awk was the fastest way to do it, i think, and im using it now. basename what? could you more spesific? or type the command for that?

Comment: There's a command `basename "$file" .test.txt` that would remove the directory prefix and the `.test.txt` suffix from the file name, leaving just `testing` for the sample name.  It takes one file name at a time.  What is the basis for removing `.text.txt`?  What should be done with `testing/.test.txt`?  With `testing/abc.def`?  With `testing/test.txt.extra`? With `testing.text.txt.extra`?

Comment: I amy be missing something, but `echo "test/testing.test.txt" | awk '{n=split($0, ar, /\//); split(ar[n], ar2, /\./); print ar2[1]}'`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Do you mean that the command was ask ' basename FILENAME' ? inside of the testing folder was contains many of file with format abd.def.txt, as my understanding, your explanation about using basename function in awk can get the name file like i wanted, cmmiw?

Comment: @dawg Your code was running as i expected, but im talking for the file name inside the folder, not path inside the file. using $0 its look like refer for path inside the file. but actually i mean is the file name inside the folder.

Comment: @dawg I have folder test, the full path was D:\test\testing.test.txt inside test folder many files with format abc.def.txt, like testing.test.txt, testingA.testA.txt, and so on. my main goal was to get only the file name such as abc,testing,testingA .

Comment: There is a command called `basename` just like there is a command called `awk`.  There isn't a `basename` function in `awk`, AFAIK.

Comment: @dawg Im using this script :awk 'function basename(file) {
    sub(".*/", "", file)
    return file
  }
  {print basename(FILENAME)}' but the result was full path

Comment: AWK 'END{ var=FILENAME;n=split (var,a,/\//); print a[n]}' , but the result still the same, D:\Latihan\test1.txt and D:\Latihan\test2.txt. all i wanted was test1 and test2.

Answer (score 1):

Use -F to delimit by the period and print the first string before that delimiter:

```
awk -F'.' '{ print $1 }'
```

Alternatively,

```
ls -l | awk '{ print $9 }' | awk -F"." '{ print $1 }'
```

will run through the whole folder

*(there's a fancier way to do it, but that's easy).*

Answer (score 0):

Use the sub and/or split functions to extract the part of FILENAME you want.

Comment: how the right format? im new in awk, could you give me an example?

Comment: im using this script: awk 'function basename(file) {
    sub(".*/", "", file)
    return file
  }
  {print basename(FILENAME)}' but still return a full path, do you have any solution?

Comment: You're on the right track. Look at @dawg's comment.